# OSX Catalina broke osascript launch with administrator priviledges

Tags: java, launch, administrator, macos-catalina

All known prior macOS versions were working with this sort of script context:

```
osascript -e "/path/to/my/app.command" with administrator privileges
```

Now it just silently fails...after asking for admin password.
The command file is what was originally used to launch the app, and the app has a button to re-launch with privileges...and the prior non privileged app closes.

If I remove the "with administrator privileges", it re-launches.  if that is there, it does not.

If I try using:

```
/usr/bin/security execute-with-privileges /path/to/my/app.command
```

It also fails...never even shows password prompt.

I tried also "sudo open /Applications/myApp.app" but that of course doesn't actually launch with privileges.

From a shell i can sudo launch my app, and that is fine, but I can't expect an average user to be able to do sudo in a shell.

As I said, this had been a nice method that has worked for probably the past 6 to 8 years...but now fails.  Anyone have any tricks or ways to get around it?

At one time....and I have no idea why, I saw the OSX security popup indicating "java" is not a trusted app and my settings only allow app store apps.  But that only happened once...and it was strange.  I clicked OK, it disappeared.  I thought maybe java had been quarantined, so I did the command to clear that flag:

```
xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /path/to/the/binary/java
```

But that made no difference.  I'm sure this is new security features in Catalina making things difficult...but I can't figure out why or how to work through them.  Its a java app that is launched via the app.command file which finds java on the machine and then launches it...defaulting to finding a local copy in its own subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout out the sandbox settings of your project. the `App Sandbox` should be set as false in the entitlements file. 
The sandboxing feature prevents your app from elevating the privilege in your app.
reference: https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/

Comment: Accepting this answer.  In short, if you are not using XCode and developing a native OSX app, you can no longer do various privileged activities, even if prompting a user to do those privileged activities.  The results of the escalation is simply ignored.  My app is a java app, and has the java binaries in the app, but launches via a script.command file, and so therefore doesn't meet the requirements Apple has.  XCode is of no use to me.